# Same font, different size on different platforms

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text, font-size

I received few PSDs from a designer who are using windows. The font is Open Sans, I already have it on my mac.

I opened the PSDs, and clicked in the text layer:

[image: After click]

[image]

..after that I edited the text, and the font changed, it seems smaller (it's still opensans, but different)
 I downloaded the font from fontsquirrel.com. Do you know guys how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common culprit is that you both have different fonts...albeit ones that are named the same. With commercial fonts, this is usually due to you both having a font produced by a different foundry. With Open Sans, that's a bit more odd, but it could be that you have slightly different versions of the typeface. Make sure you are both using the exact same font...ideally the cross platform OpenType format.

Comment: I received the font, it's good in photoshop but in firefox the accented charachters are bold. What's wrong with that?

Comment: In addition the downloaded opensans font is different too in the browser window than in the ps.

Comment: @user1452062 the font will always render differently in PhotoShop than in the browser--in fact, it's likely to render differently from browser to browser. 'tis the nature of the beast.

Comment: As I said before I have an other Open Sans font, what's fully same but the accented charachters are bold. For example: öá, what cause this?

Comment: I have no idea other than perhaps it was a font that was extended by someone that wasn't all that good at typography. They may have cut-and-pasted bold characters into the standard font and released that.

Comment: Yes, I think too. It seems I have to update the font in all psd. Thank you!